# easiest way to send/receive character from Universal window application (Windows 10 IOT) to Android

Tags: networking, bluetooth, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I want to send and receive some characters from my universal windows applications which will run on windows 10 Iot core, to my android app.
please help me thanks :)

Comment: You can utilize bluetooth RFCOMM, there is a [UWP sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothRfcommChat) you can reference. Or using WiFi Direct, here is [a sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WiFiDirect).

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have tried WiFi direct but its showing many errors some like this :  'WiFiDirectConfigurationMethod' could not be found and also i tried bluetooth code but also showing error :(

Comment: You need to show which step you halted or which line cause these errors.